# How to use nested Switch with commandline arguments?

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I have my switch case and statements inside my main function as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int c;
  while((c = getopt(argc,argv,"ABS"))!=-1)
    {
      switch(c)
      {
        case 'A':
         flag = 0;
         printf("open the port\n");
         struct can_frame frame_rd;
         open_port("vcan0");
         printf("vcan0 port is opened");
         fflush(stdout);
         create_file();
         while(1)
         {
           read_port(&frame_rd);
         }
         break;
       case 'B':
        flag = 1;
         printf("open the port\n");
         open_port("vcan0");
         printf("vcan0 port is opened");
         fflush(stdout);
         create_binfile();
         while(1)
         {
           read_port(&frame_rd);
         }
         break;
      }
}
```

Now I want to make use of nested switch when user passes an argument -S inside the `case A` can i do it as follows? Is the following procedure correct?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int c;
  while((c = getopt(argc,argv,"ABS"))!=-1)
    {
      switch(c)
      {
        case 'A':

          switch(c)
           {
             case 'S':
               size = 100;
               break;
           }
         flag = 0;
         printf("open the port\n");
         struct can_frame frame_rd;
         open_port("vcan0");
         printf("vcan0 port is opened");
         fflush(stdout);
         create_file();
         while(1)
         {
           read_port(&frame_rd);
         }
         break;
       case 'B':
        flag = 1;
         printf("open the port\n");
         open_port("vcan0");
         printf("vcan0 port is opened");
         fflush(stdout);
         create_binfile();
         while(1)
         {
           read_port(&frame_rd);
         }
         break;
      }
}
```

In the above code can I use same `switch(c)` for the nested case also , is the usage of nested switch correct?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, within the outer swich case 'A', variable c can be thought of as constant, therefore your nested switch will not find a case to match and does not have a default case.

If you know your arguments are in a particular order, you can address them directly e.g. argv[1] and argv[2] for the first and second arguments.

Comment: if i take `int i`, how can i give `i = getopt(argc,argv, "ABS")` in while loop? and i want to use `switch(i)` inside my `case A`. Is it possible?

Comment: Ohh ... then I have to do like this.. use if else.. `if argv[2]==S             { size = 100 ;                                                                                          } else {                                                                                                size = 1000;                                                                                         }` followed by my `case A`

Comment: @sp5 yes, as long as your arguments remain in order. there are plenty of tutorials on passing command line switch arguments and how to parse them in arbitrary order. it's usually looping over the argv arrary and doing something for each argument; having dependencies between arguments is likely poor design.